# vector float , constructor

Tags: java, poo

tengo duda con el siguiente ejercicio ,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Alumno {
    private String nombre;
    private float Vnotas [];


    public Alumno(String nombre , int cantidad  ){
        this.nombre= nombre ; 
        Vnotas = new Float[cantidad]; // me dice que son de tipos incompatibles , debo realizar un casting = ? 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en que has puesto `new Float` con la f en mayusculas. Esto es un error, porque estarías instanciando un `array` tipo *float* en *Float* que no existe en tu programa.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
public class Alumno {
    private String nombre;
    private float Vnotas [];


    public Alumno(String nombre , int cantidad  ){
       this.nombre= nombre ; 
       Vnotas = new float[cantidad]; //f minúscula 
   }
}
```

Comment: lo volvi a corregir y neatbeans me sigue marcando el error.:
public class Alumno {
  
   private String nombre ;
  private float Vnotas[];
  
  public Alumno(String nom, int cantidad ){
      nombre =  nom;
        Vnotas =  new float Vnotas[cantidad];
    
  }

Comment: Te da error de compatibilidad u otro error?

Comment: me da el error incompatible types : possible lossy comvertion from float to int,